# Is there an EF.Functions.ContainsTable() equivalent?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, freetext, freetexttable

There's an [EF.Functions.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions-contains(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-object-system-string-system-int32)) and [EF.Functions.FreeText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions-freetext(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-object-system-string-system-int32)). But I can't find a ContainsTable() or FreeTextTable(). Is the only way to do those to use `FromSqlInterpolated()`?

And if so, is this the correct usage:

```
dbContext.AppUsers.FromSqlInterpolated($@"SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(AppUsers, *, {Query}) as t INNER JOIN AppUsers u on u.Id = t.[KEY]").ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Please upvote issue [#11487](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11487)

Comment: @bricelam Done. And I assume that means now at present. If you write that as an answer, including the request to vote, happy to accept it.

Comment: Meant "... means **no** at ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per the comment by @bricelam above the answer is no. And if you'd like to get this added, [please vote here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11487).